# efficient DELETE in proto-Van Emde Boas Tree?

Tags: data-structures, trees, balanced-search-trees, van-emde-boas-trees

TLDR: CLRS is claiming that a certain "pseudo" or "proto" tree structure does not have fast deletion, but I seem to have an algorithm that is efficient, and I would like to know whether it works or not.

In particular:

In Section 20.2.1 of CRLS, the book introduces a "proto" Van Emde Boas (vEB) structure that has some, but all, of the features of true vEB trees. At the end of the section, it says

> The DELETE operation is more complicated than insertion. Whereas we can always set a summary bit to 1 when inserting, we cannot always reset the same summary bit to 0 when deleting. We need to determine whether any bit in the appropriate cluster is 1. As we have defined proto-vEB structures, we would have to examine all $\sqrt u$ bits within a cluster to determine whether any of them are 1.

However, that last claim seems dubious, since the summary structure itself already tells you that information, so that you don't *have* to "examine all $\sqrt u$ bits within a cluster to determine whether any of them are 1."

In particular, exercise 20.2-2 asks for an implementation of PROTO-vEB-DELETE that "scans related bits within the cluster". The following seems to work in O(lg u) time *without* scanning any bits, except in the base case of `V.n == 2`! Of course the *true* vEB tree has O(lg lg u) deletion, so the below is still inferior to that.

```
PROTO-vEB-DELETE(V, x)     
  if V.n == 2
    V.A[x] = 0
    return  V.A[1-x] == 0
  else
    return PROTO-vEB-DELETE(V.A[high(x)], low(x))
        && PROTO-vEB-DELETE(V.summary, high(x))
```

`PROTO-vEB-DELETE(V, x)` deletes element x from the vEB structure V, and returns TRUE if and only if the deletion of x caused V to become completely empty. This algorithm seems to have complexity $T(u) = 2 T(\sqrt u) + O(1)$, which becomes $T(u) = O(\lg u)$. Does this algorithm actually work?

Comment: I have the same question too. Have you managed to find any answer for it now?